# React - Can't get CDN font to work on Safari Browsers

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, safari

I'm using a font called `Track`. I have a create-react-app that is in production. The font works on some browsers. I've set up my own s3 bucket through digital ocean to help me serve static files. I thought it would be best to also download the font files into the same bucket and then use the URL to serve it to my production app.

Here is how I set up my `index.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Track';
  src: local('Track') url('https://.../fonts/Track-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

However, this does not work. Currently just looking at Times New Roman font on display in safari mobile browser.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this. It applies the font face to the component.

```
div {
    font-family: 'Track';
}
```

Adding this instead should be better.

```
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pattaya';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pattaya/v6/ea8ZadcqV_zkHY-XBdOt9kRHiVqtCg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* thai */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pattaya';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pattaya/v6/ea8ZadcqV_zkHY-XBcOt9kRHiVqtCg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0E01-0E5B, U+200C-200D, U+25CC;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pattaya';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pattaya/v6/ea8ZadcqV_zkHY-XBdit9kRHiVqtCg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pattaya';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pattaya/v6/ea8ZadcqV_zkHY-XBdmt9kRHiVqtCg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pattaya';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pattaya/v6/ea8ZadcqV_zkHY-XBdet9kRHiVo.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More context needed.

Where is the snippet that applies the font?

```
div {
    font-family: 'Track';
}
```